# What is a good syntax for Python and Redis together

Tags: python, redis

When I type

```
r = redis.StrictRedis(host='localhost', port=637, db=0, decode_responses=True, charset='utf-8')
for i in r.keys('*'):
print(i)
```

Python gives an error `WinError 10061`.
What is the problem?

Comment: What is the full traceback of that error. I believe that is a connection refused error. Did you ensure that you started your redis server with the appropriate credentials you are trying to use to connect?

Comment: look i am not prof in redis so i started with that code
i dont know how to start redis server.
ib the server side what i need to write redis.redis or what

Comment: You are trying to connect to a redis server. I am assuming that you have already started redis locally on your machine? Are you following a tutorial?

Comment: my knowledge is redis docs so i don`t have much reference
could some body show my a server side and a client for a reference

Comment: Have you looked at [a Redis quickstart guide](https://redis.io/topics/quickstart)? That has instructions on how to start your server. Also, it looks like the default port is 6379, but your code just has 637 - that might be why you are getting a connection refused error.